# Getting System.StackOverflowException after upgrading Automapper from version 4.x.x to 5

Tags: c#, automapper

We were using Automapper for years in multiple projects from version 3 to 4.2.1 I think and we had no problems mapping our entities to DTOs and vice versa. Suddenly after upgrading to version 5.0.2. Now all the objects which had circular references caused the `Map` method to throw System.StackOverflowException, other objects with primitive properties were mapped just fine. We rolled back to version 4.2.1 and it works fine.

There should be some configuration that enables the mapper to handle circular references or we are just using it the wrong way (deprecated way).

Answer (score 1):

After some digging I found out that when creating maps using `CreateMap` method, we just needed to call another method named `PreserveReferences` which preserves references in circular references and does exactly what we wanted. Our code looks like this:

```
_config = new AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration(cfg => 
{
    foreach(var mapping in _mappings) 
    {
        cfg.CreateMap(mapping.Source, mapping.Destination).PreserveReferences();
    }
});

_mapper = _config.CreateMapper();
```

This small change was about to make a disaster for us! Fortunately we found the solution. There is a discussion [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1398) about this issue.